# Cannot connect to Github via ssh, cannot access .ssh.config

Tags: git, github, ssh, vagrant

I'm new to Git and command line. I am using a Vagrant virtual box.

Today, I tried pushing some work to Github and got the error:

> connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused

A SE post suggested I try to use: `ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com,` but I got the same message:

> connect to host ssh.github.com port 443: Connection refused

Another post suggested I check the ssh config settings with `~/.ssh/config`, but I get:

> zsh: permission denied: /home/vagrant/.ssh/config

I'm not really sure what to do next. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you follow this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/), but it is very helpful.

You are having `permission denied` to access `~/.ssh/config` because this file, just can be edited by the machine admin.

If you are de admin, do `sudo vim ~/.ssh/config` and then enter with your password and edit the file.

Sometimes, the ssh problem is because you have changed your ssh key, so if the problem insists, remove ssh keys and add then again

`sudo rm -rf ~/.ssh/` (**WARNING: THIS WILL REMOVE ALL SSH KEYS**)

Comment: `nano` instead of `vim` ? sudo and nano are different commands, try remove `sudo` and `vim` and just use `nano` should work too :)